# Introducing blank spaces and line breaks into title string?

Tags: html, razor, newline, spaces

How do I modify the following code to break the Title string value into two lines?
The center align doesn't seem to work either. Am I missing something?

```
@{ 
    Html.RenderAction(
        "GenericPopupPartial", 
        "Shared", 
        new { 
            containerName = "registerSuccess",  
            BodyHtml = Model.MessageSent, 
            Title = "Thank you for registering!       Our representatives will  review your request and email you with access to our product section shortly." 
            }
        );
}

<a class="fbox1" id="registerSuccess-link" href="#registerSuccess" style="display: none; text-align:center;"></a>
```

Output as follows:

> Thanks for registering! Our representatives will  review your request
>   and email you with access to our product section shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.MultiLineText)
```

and include the \n character between the lines

the following will replace the 'break'  character with a new line. Maybe try that.

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.MultiLineText).Replace("\n", "<br />")){"GenericPopupPartial", 
    "Shared", 
    new { 
        containerName = "registerSuccess",  
        BodyHtml = Model.MessageSent, 
        Title = "Thank you for registering! <br /> Our representatives will  review your request and email you with access to our product section shortly." 
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you mean: @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.MultiLineText).Html.RenderAction(
        "GenericPopupPartial",......................?

Comment: sorry didn;t read your comment carefully before replying no just add the .RenderAction

Comment: you might not even need it i haven't tested it but just put that code before your function and it should work..

Comment: i might have missed a bracket somewhere but you get the jist

Answer (score 1):

Try `\n`:

```
Title = "Thank you for registering!\nOur representatives will  review your request and email you with access to our product section shortly."
```